# Web3 multiplying values

Tags: web3js, blockchain

I retrieve the amount of tokens from a certain wallet address and want to multiply this * 0.979 and use that value in a smart contract interaction.

Multiplying seems to cause it to overflow.
What is the proper way to multiply such values?

```
const amountAMin = (amountPear) * 0.979
```

Returns: `(fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=11095596053108748000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.4.2)`

amountPear = 11333601688568690945 , the smart contract expects a uint256

Comment: Why do you need amountPear in brackets? Could that be affecting it? Also I don’t think you can update or re-declare const so it is possible you’re calling it earlier as well?

Comment: Omitting the brackets doesnt help. I think it has to do something with the value type / mismatch. It give the right value, but not in the right type I assume. amountPear is a string, while aMountMin ends up as a number